# Setting markers by lat and lng values

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a problem. I'm sending to JavaScript strings with lat and lng values. Then, in JavaScript I use the `split()` method, and gets an array with this values. How can I draw all markers? This function doesn't work properly - the markers aren't created on the map. What is wrong?

```
                var lngstring = <%=lngstring %>
                var latstring = <%=latstring %>
                alert(latstring);
                alert(lngstring);
                var arraylat = latstring.split("#");
                var arraylng = lngstring.split("#");
                alert(arraylat.length) // 200
                for (var i = 0; i < arraylat.length; i++) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(arraylat[i],arraylng[i]),
                        map: map
                        });
                        //alert(arraylat[i],arraylng[i]);
                 }
                 alert("ready!");
                 alert(arraylat[2]); // 37.789879
                 alert(arraylng[2]); // -122.39044200000001
```

Comment: Whats the format of your latstring , what does it look like?

Comment: Have you checked the map object, does it have a map reference.

Comment: "18.69872650000002#14.971600200000012#15.58599490000006#16.077066699999932" -> my latstring. What do you mean with map object?

Comment: where in your code do you set the map  object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote `<%=lngstring %>` and `<%=latstring %>` to mark them as a `string`:

```
var lngstring = "<%=lngstring %>";   
var latstring = "<%=latstring %>";
```

otherwise you will have something like this:

```
var lngstring = 18.69872650000002#14.971600200000012#15.58599490000006#16.077066699999932;
```

which is invalid javascript, and Browser can't parse it.

Comment: yeah, i forget about it. In other function i did this, but now not :) problem is solved ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do not set a map object, it can be set like below, use this before adding your marker.

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 12
};
var map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

In HTML

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: i have it earlier in script, i set map object. Map is visible

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and Longitude values need to be numbers.  Call parseFloat() on the strings you are passing in to the LatLng constructor:

change:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(arraylat[i],arraylng[i])
```

to:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(arraylat[i]),parseFloat(arraylng[i]))
```

Comment: it wasn't the problem, but big thx for help :) problem solved